# How make certain field (search box) active when page loads

Tags: html, css

When a user loads my page, the first element to become active in the browser is one of my menu buttons.

I have a search box (form field) on my page that I want to be the first thing active.

What I mean by "active" is that when the user pushes the tab button, it cycles through all the elements on the site, right. And if users use tab on my site they have to cycle through all the menu buttons before coming to the search field.

Is there a way to say to the browser, "make this field the first active one on page load"?
So that when the page has loaded, the user can start typing in the search field right away.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use autofocus for that. Using javascript you can do

```
document.onload = function() {  
  document.getElementById("textField").focus();
}
```

OR

you can directly use it as follows

```
Search : <input type="text" name="search" autofocus><br>
```

You can read more about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp) and can try it out [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_autofocus).

Comment: np :) Also do not forget to accept the answer if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

It will be best option for case

```
   <input type="text" name="YourSearch" id="YourSearch" autofocus>
```